# How to call run/invoke a local application inside google chrome

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome

In out local intranet, we have a website that will be only used inside our intranet.

Before we use it in internet explorer, there are lots of page using JavaScript + ActiveX to open local applications, like Microsoft excel etc.

Now we want to shift to using Google Chrome, but we don't know to call these applications inside Chrome.
Is it possible to do in Google Chrome? Or is there any extensions of Chrome can do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [NPAPI Plugins](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html): "You can bundle an NPAPI plugin with your extension, allowing you to call into native binary code from JavaScript."

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the new desktop notification from google, that does work really outside the browser, so you can have look on its concepts and try to mimic its techniques!

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [Native Client SDK](http://code.google.com/chrome/nativeclient/) for Google Chrome.